# Javascript to randomly add/subtract to a number every second

Tags: javascript, random

What I want my function to achieve for my javascript function is for every second to either randomly subtract or add (a random number) to a number held in a div.

Here's what I have so far.

It doesn't work, it seems to append the number to the end of the div value (100), and also it doesn't take into account that I want it to either randomly add or subtract (it just adds at the moment)

```
    setInterval(function(){
        random = (Math.floor((Math.random()*15)+1)); 
        currentnumber = document.getElementById('number');

        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML =  currentnumber + random;

     }, 1000);
```

Comment: `currentnumber` should probably be `.innerHTML` and not the element itself.

Comment: Maybe you could try currentnumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').innerHTML); ?  (edit: yes innerHTML is what you're after, otherwise you're manipulating the DOM object)

Comment: For the record, this question was a clear oversight of missing `innerHTML` when declaring the variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

parse the current value as an integer, and then do another math.random and use it to decide negative or positive.  Lastly, you need to use the innerHTML of currentnumber, not the entire node.  So something like this should work:

```
setInterval(function(){
    random = (Math.floor((Math.random()*15)+1));
    var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
    random = random * plusOrMinus; 
    currentnumber = document.getElementById('number');

    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML =  parseInt(currentnumber.innerHTML) + random;

 }, 1000);
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cT7a9/2/)

Comment: post the fiddle, I'm sure you're using more code than what you posted

Comment: @JuergPodolski added working fiddle.  you needed to also use the innerhtml of currentnumber besides just parsing it as an integer.

Comment: Nice! Thanks Rooster much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`.innerHTML` returns you a string which you'll need to parse into an integer to perform the addition or subtraction. Have a look at a number of methods listed in the following SO question

[How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

`currentnumber` is a DOM object, and you can't add that to a number.

```
var div = document.getElementById('number');
div.innerHTML = Number(div.innerHTML) + 3;
```

Notice you are getting the `innerHTML` of the `div`, converting that to a `Number()`, adding your random number to it, and THEN setting your `div.innerHTML` to your new value.

http://jsfiddle.net/9LqQG/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    random = (Math.floor((Math.random()*15)+1)); 
    currentnumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').innerHTML);

    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML =  currentnumber + random;
 }, 1000);
```

Your `currentnumber` variable needs to get the innerHTML of the element, then parse the string into an integer.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YKKW/)